# css/less: apply attribute globally at once for specific tag (ex> <a> tag)

Tags: css, meteor, less, ratchet

This could be quite simple or silly duplicated but I can't find exact answer.

I used two UI framework, ratchet & bootstrap, for Meteor Cordova project,
and after I added bootstrap, it override a tag's attribute to be shown underline.

I can remove it by text-decoration: none; by add style for each a tag, but I just want to add this attribute to the whole a tags in this project.

Is there a way to do this with css or less?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Just make sure that this declaration comes *after* both of the other stylesheets or it will be overwritten by one of them.